# how we sort query result on the occurrence of keyword strength in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

**below is my query.**

i want result like where occurrence of words high its come on the first post .... and so on but my query not give proper result like my requirement....if you see below attach image where "adolf" is on 5th number ....bu i want its going on last number because in this post occurrence of word very low....
kindly help me and advance sorry of my english

$search =**"adolf import export"**;

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    MATCH (c_name,n_business,city,country) AGAINST ('$serach' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Relevance
FROM tbl_services 
WHERE 
    MATCH (c_name,n_business,city,country) AGAINST ('$serach*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  
ORDER BY 
    Relevance DESC 
LIMIT $page1 , 12
```

above query result below:
[image]

Comment: First of all, you seem to have a problem with your variable name. Typo?

Comment: i accepted but how sort post according to occurrence of the keyword strength as i above mention

Comment: no one here for help?

Comment: This would be a nice MapReduce job. I'd not done this with a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what u want.

```
SELECT 
    title,
    description,    
    ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH(description)
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( description, "value", "") ) 
        ) / LENGTH("value")        
    ) AS count    
FROM <table>
```